# How to get a better spacing in nested multicols environments?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, multicol

The following code produces an output that has badly-spaced contents. My objective is to write an exercise with multiple choice questions. Each option may have a figure.

[image]

The red arrows indicate the badly-spaced parts.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=10pt
\usepackage{enumerate}

\def\question{%
Which is the correct statement about a quadratic function?}

\def\option{%
When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$-intercepts as shown in the figure below.

\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{foo}
\end{center}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Exercise}]
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
% Question 1
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols} 
% Question 2
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
% Question 3
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols} 
% Question 4
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How to get a better spacing in nested `multicols` environments? I also noticed the spacing gets weird in both text mode and math mode.

If this problem is not easy to fix, is there another way to accomplish my objective, i.e., creating a multiple-choice exercise with the same layout as shown above?

Comment: Can you please explain the terms "The current answers do not contain enough detail" and "I am looking for a better solution"? What sort of additional detail are you looking for? and in what respect do you expect a solution to be better?

Comment: You need to be more specific, the layout you illustrated above shows a __four__ column text with the image below the option, whereas the comments you have been making on both my answer and the accepted answer was pointing that _maybe_ you want wrapped images. As I also said on my last comment, you need to post somewhere say at `pastebin`, actual text and images. Layouts react differently to sizing that varies and sometimes is not always possible to achieve good balance between the columns. .

Comment: Where did you see that my solution needs  reconfiguring. What I have been asking you was to post real questions and answers for _testing_ the code and I see no reason why you ducking the request. Anyway this was my 2cents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How do you like this? May be it could be an approach for you. It was done with the `picins`-package.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=10pt
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{picins}

\def\question{%
Which is the correct statement about a quadratic function?}

\def\option{%
When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$-intercepts as shown in the figure below.\picskip{0}%
}

\def\fig{%
\parpic(3cm,3cm)[rd]{\includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{foo}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Exercise}]
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
% Question 1
\item \question
\begin{enumerate}
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
\end{enumerate}
\item \question
\begin{enumerate}
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
\end{enumerate}
\item \question
\begin{enumerate}
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
\end{enumerate}
\item \question
\begin{enumerate}
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
 \item\fig\option
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us more details about your requirements. Maybe we can provide other examples which fits your needs.

Comment: @ Counter Terrorist: Did you tried my example? The text is floating around the figure. I inserted an second picture where you can see it. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 12):

The nesting of enumeration environments and multicolumn layouts is always problematic.  Besides the code becomes messy quickly and will be difficult to use. The user commands should be able to run as:

```
\begin{...}[]
\question{}
\option{}
\option{}

\question{}
\option{}
\option{}
\end{...}
```

And give you this:

[image]

Here is the MWE code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=1.5em
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% better try a real example
\def\demoplot{%
\pgfplotsset{width=120pt,compat=1.3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
% some counters 
\newcounter{ctr}\setcounter{ctr}{0}
\newcounter{ctrr}[ctr]\setcounter{ctrr}{0}
% to step counters and add some style
\def\inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctr}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \color{blue}\thectr.
}
\def\Inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctrr}
  \color{purple}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \alph{ctrr}.
}
% question 
\newcommand\question[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\inc \hfill}}{%
     #1\par}%
}
% demo question
\newcommand{\demoquestion}{%
 \question{Which is the correct statement about 
      a quadratic function?}
}
% option
\newcommand\option[2]{%
  \vbox{\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\Inc}}{#1}
  \end{minipage}\hskip10pt\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
     \vspace*{5.5pt}%
     \centering%
     #2%\rule{80pt}{80pt}%#2
     \vspace{5.5pt}
  \end{minipage}\par}
}%
% option for demo
\newcommand{\demooption}{%
  \option{When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$- 
         intercepts as shown in the figure 
         below.}{\demoplot}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\textcolor{purple}{EXERCISE}}]
    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

   \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption


    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

An alternative plan as per comments:

[image]

and a new MWE:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=1.5em
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\def\demoplot{%
\pgfplotsset{width=110pt,compat=1.3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ctr}\setcounter{ctr}{0}
\newcounter{ctrr}[ctr]\setcounter{ctrr}{0}

\def\inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctr}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \color{blue}\thectr.
}
\def\Inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctrr}
  \color{purple}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \alph{ctrr}.
}
% Demo question
\newcommand\question[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\inc \hfill}}{%
     #1\par}%
}

\newcommand{\demoquestion}{%
 \question{Which is the correct statement about 
      a quadratic function?}
 \medskip
}
% Demo answer
\newcommand\option[2]{%
  \vbox{\hbox to \linewidth{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\Inc}}{#1}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%\hskip0.05\textwidth
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
     \vspace{-6pt} 
     \centering%
     \fbox{#2}%\rule{80pt}{80pt}%#2
  \end{minipage}\par}}
\smallskip
}%


\newcommand{\demooption}{%
  \option{When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$- 
         intercepts as shown in the figure 
         below.}{\demoplot}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\textcolor{purple}{EXERCISE}}]
    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

   \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption


    \demoquestion
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption
    \demooption

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Add on code for wrapped figures.**

We use the `wrapfig` package to wrap text to figures and still avoid lists. So what we do we build up the indentation and counters. The result looks like:

[image]

And the final MWE example:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=1.5em
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% better try a real example
\def\demoplot{%
\pgfplotsset{width=120pt,compat=1.3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2 - x +4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\parindent0pt
\makeatletter
% some counters 
\newcounter{ctr}\setcounter{ctr}{0}
\newcounter{ctrr}[ctr]\setcounter{ctrr}{0}
% to step counters and add some style
\def\inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctr}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \color{blue}\thectr.
}
\def\Inc{%
  \stepcounter{ctrr}
  \color{purple}
  \bfseries\sffamily
  \alph{ctrr}.
}
% question 
\newcommand\question[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\inc \hfill}}{%
     #1\par}%
}
% demo question
\newcommand{\demoquestion}{%
 \question{Which is the correct statement about 
      a quadratic function?}
}
% option
\newcommand\option[2]{%
  \vbox{\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\Inc}}{#1}
  \end{minipage}\hskip10pt\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
     \vspace*{5.5pt}%
     \centering%
     #2%\rule{80pt}{80pt}%#2
     \vspace{5.5pt}
  \end{minipage}\par}
}%
% option for demo
\newcommand{\demooption}{%
  \option{When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$- 
         intercepts as shown in the figure 
         below.}{\demoplot}
}

\newcommand\WrapFigure[1]{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt} 
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[-10pt]{100pt}%
\demoplot %the image
\end{wrapfigure}
\hskip-20pt\@hangfrom{\hbox to 15pt{\Inc}}
\leftskip15pt
#1\par 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}[\section*{\textcolor{purple}{EXERCISE}}]
\WrapFigure{%
This is a test of some sort to check it out. 
To see what is happening here. This is a test of some sort to check it out. To see what is happening here.\par
This is a test of some sort to check it out. 
To see what is happening here. This is a test of some sort to check it out. To see what is happening here.}
\medskip
\leftskip0pt
\demooption
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You example looks good. But how can you align the text so that the text and the picture starts on the same height? It seams that the text is aligned to the bottom of the picture. If there is little text and a huge picture it looks strange. And how can you right-align the pictures to the question text?

Comment: @Holle First the right-align (replace `\hskip10pt` with `\hfill` and will align. You might think it is not due to the space around the TikZ figure. Just replace `#2` with `\fbox{#2}` in the `\option` definition and you will see what I mean. Will modify as per your suggestions a bit later and recapture a new image.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist I wouldn't recommend that it does. It is bad typography for this type of text. I would post some code tomorrow for it as a separate command, then you can used both.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist Please see revisions.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist If you post somewhere 2 real questions and 5 actual options, I will give it a try. I am no too kin to test a layout only on sample data. I mean otherwise it is easy to wrap commands in a macro to test.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist Perhaps come over to chat and discuss a bit further. Just ping me when you there.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist I opted out from revising, after seeing the pastebin post. You kept referring to see image below and you kept accepting answers for wrapped content;)

Comment: @CounterTerrorist I think there is some strangeness. I struggled to understand what you wanted. Then as I mentioned above, you kept to referring `to see figure below` in the paste bin text. NONE of the answers here are done that way and in NO comment you intimated this.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist It is very confusing "dummy text". As well as very confusing image in the original question. Let's leave it as such, as I mentioned earlier I did not do any revisions to the original post. I am glad that you now have solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the `center` environment with `\centering` and use `raggedcolumns` you get better results:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=10pt
\usepackage{enumerate}

\def\question{%
Which is the correct statement about a quadratic function?}

\def\option{%
When $D<0$, the graph has 2 $x$-intercepts as shown in the figure below.

\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{foo}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{Exercise}]\raggedcolumns
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
% Question 1
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols} 
% Question 2
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
% Question 3
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols} 
% Question 4
\item \question
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a.]
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option
        \item \option   
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On "normal" paper (i.e, `\usepackage{geometry}`) it does not look so bad. I suspect with the different paper size the problem has something to do with column balancing, but don't know how to help you further.